# OledbConnection Close and/or Dispose are very slow, take 20s to execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, excel, oledbconnection

While using OleDbConnection to access sheet names of the excel files I encountered a problem. Everything in the code executes fine and works, until the OleDbConnection closes at the end of the using statement. This causes the program to stop for 15-20 seconds or more!

I've tried getting rid of the using statement and individually using the OleDbConnection.Close() and OleDbConnection.Dispose() methods, both of those take incredibly long to execute as well. If I never close the connection at all, the program runs perfectly.

```
//Closing connection is inredibly slow now for some reason
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    DataTable dbSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    sheetNames.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dbSchema.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sheetNames.Add(dbSchema.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                    }
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(sheetNames.ToArray());
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    //conn.Close();
                }
//Connection strings
//XLS
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;';" />
//XLSX
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;';"
```

A very strange thing I noticed is that the connection takes very long to close for every type of excel file EXCEPT .xls files (from 1997-2003 era Excel).

On top of all this I've searched everywhere on the internet and cannot actually find anyone who has found a solution to this, only unsolved forum posts. Here are a few links I've found from those with the same problem:

[OleDbConnection close method taking long execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180822/oledbconnection-close-method-taking-long-execution-time),

[OleDbConnection Dispose very slow (2s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206430/oledbconnection-dispose-very-slow-2s)

http://forums.asp.net/t/2059359.aspx?OledbConnection+Close+taking+too+long+to+execute

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar performance issue when closing OLE DB connections to Access databases. A suggestion from a related question resolved the issue: adding the following to the connection string:

```
OLE DB Services=-1;
```

I can't reproduce the issue with Excel workbooks, but this may also work for those.

Comment: Confirm, this solved my problem with a very long connection time to the Ms Access database. Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two years later and Gurch's response helped me out. Thanks.

My app uses OleDb Connector to Access Database file.

I did need to modify how I opened db file later to compute checksum.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

FileShare.ReadWrite seemed to be key, was using System.IO.File.OpenRead Previously.